# Is it plagiarism if only a short phrase or construct is the same?

Tags: journals, plagiarism

Suppose we have some text in a scientific journal article A. It is a verbatim copy of some text published in a related article B which is referenced by A, and this phrase is used to explain the same topic in both articles. However, the phrase itself is short, not a complete sentence and not very relevant (it could have been written in many different ways) but it seems the author of A has taken it from the original (B). Is this text plagiarism? I would rephrase it because it looks like a copy (it's unlikely it happened by chance given that the paragraphs in the two publications are related and the reference to B appears in a nearby paragraph) and that's not elegant according to my style and taste, but is there a general rule?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is not a fixed set of rules for what is considered plagiarism (e.g., "5 or more consecutive, not quoted words"), although [several guidelines](https://www.google.it/search?q=plagiarism+guidelines) are available. Unless entire paragraphs are copy-pasted, each case has to be evaluated on a single basis.

As for a partial sentence, it is *likely not* considered to be a bad case of plagiarism.

That said, it depends on what the actual sentence is about. Are [those 500+ papers](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q="in+this+paper+we+report+a+study+on") plagiarizing each others because of that partial sentence? Certainly not.

If the partial sentence was about a particular discovery reported in a particular paper, and that partial sentence was copied to a new paper *as if the sentence belonged to the new paper*, without a direct quotation.. that would likely be considered as a candidate for plagiarism. Quite for sure, it would be considered as plagiarism if a reference was missing, as well.

You might have some fun taking [this Turnitin quiz on plagiarism](http://turnitin.com/assets/en_us/media/plagiarism-quiz/).

Comment: Thank you, somehow I hadn't thought of searching for "guidelines". In this case the sentence is about a very specialized topic and it is used to explain the same idea as in the cited article. So in that case I think it is not so much a matter of ethics but of a lack of originality (or laziness) in writing style.

Comment: Did the test and the only one I got wrong was the one about secondary sources, so I learned something important. :)

Comment: Got two wrong myself and I have chaired departmental ethics and plagiarism committees.

Comment: @Stochastic I got the secondary source wrong, too.  I wonder whether there's a problem with the quiz, because I'd say, "you cannot cite Paper A unless you've read it."  I've lent my APA manual out, but I'd probably cite B and footnote A if I had not read A.  Edit: Aha! I see someone has posted a question, now on hold, about this very thing!

Answer (score 1):

"Suppose we have some text" (5 consecutive words), your first sentence, already yields 18 hits in Google.  As you mention it is "not very relevant", and you know the origin, I suggest you to rephrase it.

There are no general rules, one reason why such matters are settled in courts. One clear rules though: "Give Credit Where Credit is Due". And many guidelines, like in [Avoiding plagiarism, self-plagiarism, and other questionable writing practices: A guide to ethical writing](https://ori.hhs.gov/images/ddblock/plagiarism.pdf), Miguel Roig.

Two additional food for thought:

1. A common quote: [If You Steal From One Author, It's Plagiarism; If You Steal From Many, It's Research](http://quoteinvestigator.com/2010/09/20/plagiarism/),
2. J. L. Borges (my favorite author) wrote a novel on "[Pierre Menard, Author of the Quixote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Menard,_Author_of_the_Quixote)", which really makes you think about such matters.

Comment: As I commented on the previous answer, the phrase is not very important itself but it was probably copied. I'm suggesting the author to rephrase it (it's a paper we're working on). Thank you for the links. I like Borges but I don't remember that work, I'll check it out (I happen to be Argentine).

Comment: Many people use stuff like "Google translation", wich is partly grounded on "already written" texts (which they have scanned, on purpose). I believe is it unlikely that a 6-7 words normal sentence was never written before, but most of the time we are not aware of that.  I bought the "Obras completas" in four volumes, to give me incentives to learn castillan enough to be able to read the original texts.